# Angular 2 Persistir Menú durante la sesión

Tags: angularjs-2.0, session

Cordial saludo,

soy desarrollador que viene del mundo de webforms, allí se tenia un objeto que podría grabarse en la sesion del usuario, yo normalmente guardaba allí los datos del usuario y ademas el menú, para no tener que volver a consultarlo todo el tiempo.

existe alguna manera de hacer algo similar en angular2? probé hacerlo con cookies pero tienen una limitación de 4kb.

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe una alternativa al uso de cookies con limites más relajados que te permite almacenar datos en el navegador del cliente usando [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) y [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) ([ver ejemplos de uso](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)):

---

**Ejemplos de `sessionStorage`**

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

---

**Ejemplo de `localStorage`**

```
localStorage.colorSetting = '#a4509b';
localStorage['colorSetting'] = '#a4509b';
localStorage.setItem('colorSetting', '#a4509b');
```

---

**Estado del soporte para ambos**

```
Feature        Chrome Firefox/Gecko  IE  Opera Safari/WebKit
localStorage      4         3.5       8  10.50      4
sessionStorage    5         2         8  10.50      4
```

[Tamaños máximos y otros detalles](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/)

Comment: muy bueno ya lo probé pero como podrías ponerle el session timeout?

Comment: En este caso hablamos de datos que persisten de manera indefinida, debes guardar una marca de tiempo y controlar por software el borrado